# Typedef a bitfield variable

Tags: c, typedef, bit-fields

I want to have a typedef that is 1-bit integer, so I though of this `typedef int:1 FLAG;` but I'm getting errors with it, is there a way I can do so?
Thanks

Comment: I'd use a bool, but if I want to combine some of them together to a form a 8-bit number, will I be able to do that? Like these variables will be either 0 or 1, and later on in some stage, I'd want to combine some vars to lets say 10110, I use shifting to do so, will it work on bools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

The smallest addressable "thing" in a C Program is a *byte* or `char`.
A `char` is at least 8 bits long.
So you cannot have a type (or objects of any type) with less than 8 bits.

What you can do is have a type for which objects occupy at least as many bits as a `char` and ignore most of the bits

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct OneBit {
    unsigned int value:1;
};
typedef struct OneBit onebit;

int main(void) {
    onebit x;
    x.value = 1;
    x.value++;
    printf("1 incremented is %u\n", x.value);
    printf("each object of type 'onebit' needs %d bytes (%d bits)\n",
          (int)sizeof x, CHAR_BIT * (int)sizeof x);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the code above running at [ideone](http://ideone.com/tjVSBA).

Comment: This is the only one. The struct definition will bring the needed padding and you will be able to use your object as if it was 1-bit long.
Of course, this example is like using a nuke to kill a little bug but you will get the idea for more useful bitfield structures. (And your object will still occupy 1 byte in memory)