# Create data type with malloc()

Tags: c, memory, types, malloc

In C I wish to create a data type (like int or float) that has only 1byte. How can I possible do this? I've tried with malloc() but didn't work that way I tried.

Could you please give me a hand here?

Example:

```
sizeof(int) = 4 bytes
sizeof(char) = 1 byte
sizeof(float) = 4 bytes
sizeof(myDataType) = 1 byte
```

Comment: What did you try? There aren't many ways to do it, but it can be done.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a datatype"? Allocate storage space? Declare some type, which takes exactly one byte?

Comment: Aren't you searching for the type "char" (1byte) ?

Comment: CHECK THIS : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536736/typedef-a-bitfield-variable

Comment: @TelmoVaz: You already have a standard data type of size 1 byte: [`uint8_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). Use this happily intead of mallocing and forgetting to free it later on.

Comment: @legends2k The standard 1-byte type is `char`. Nothing guarantees that `uint8_t` takes up one byte.

Comment: @H2CO3: Then what's the point of [u]intN_t types? The only value they add is giving a guarentee on the signedness and length.

Comment: @legends2k They guarantee exact (or minimal, for `*min_t` types) **bit** width. Don't confuse bytes with octets.

Comment: I actually want to use 1byte type for integer. I wish to use it to options in switches and number menu options. And I would like to create my own data type to use it, without having to include any libraries besides stdio and stdlib

Answer (score 4):

There is such data type. `char` is always guaranteed to be one byte long. If you want another name for that type, just use `typedef` and create a new type based on `char`.

More detailed explanation can be found in this question: [Are there machines, where sizeof(char) != 1, or at least CHAR_BIT > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1)